# Word and memory address

Tags: assembly, x86

How does word address and memory address related? For example, I have a 32 bit machine. Does the address jump by 4 or by 1? Which one of the following is correct?

```
0x100: 0x 1111 2222
0x104: 0x 3333 4444

0x100: 0x 1111 2222
0x101: 0x 3333 4444
```

In case of jumping by 4, can I use 0x101 to access 11, 0x102 to access 22?

Comment: What do you mean by an address _"jumping"_? The smallest addressable unit of memory on x86 processors (as well as on many/most other CPU architectures) is a byte.

Comment: They're not. By 1. [0x101] = 0x11, [0x102] = 0x22.

Comment: Oh I mean the address of the next word. What happens if the address size is different from word size?

Comment: The word size on x86 processors is 16 bits. It's been a long time since 16-bit addressing was used on x86 processors (actually the addresses were 20-bit even with the old segmented memory model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X86 can address both bytes, words and double words (see LES/LDS/LSS) located at *almost* any addresses; more specifically the smallest addressable unit in IA is a byte; the architecture is little endian and words do not have be aligned at the word size. On x86 restrictions apply for a memory address spanning a segment: trying to access word at CS/ES/SS/DS:FFFF results in a exception.

To summarize:

```
0x100: 01 02 03 04  <-- on 32-bit architecture (386+) contains 0x04030201
0x104: 05 06 07 07

The double word located at address 0x101 contains 0x05040302.
The 16-bit word located at address 0x101 contains 0x0302 and
The byte at 0x101 contains 0x02
```